# save() in controllers, Grails

Tags: grails, save

I am creating a project in my ProjectController and it should be saved after being created. But instead it gives me the following exception:

```
 Class java.lang.ClassCastException 
Message  com.everyonecounts.padre.ProjectController$_closure1 cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletRequest
```

Here is the code for my save method:

```
def save() {
    log.debug(params)
    def projectInstance = new Project(params)
    if (!projectInstance.save(flush: false)) {
        log.debug("save failed")
        render(view: "create", model: [projectInstance: projectInstance])  
        return
    }


}
```

Stack trace tells me that the error occurs at the render line.

Comment: Can you show `Project` domain class and `create.gsp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a close look, I see that you actually are checking for errors in `save` instead of a successful save. Do you need to check for an unsuccessful save or successful?

```
def save() {
    log.debug(params)
    def projectInstance = new Project(params)
    //If save was successful then the if block will not be executed.
    if (!projectInstance.save(flush: false)) {//Returns true on successful save.
        log.debug("save failed")
        render(view: "create", model: [projectInstance: projectInstance])  
        return
    }

    //There is nothing to render here in case the save was successful.
    //you would need something like below on save success
    //render(view: "create", model: [projectInstance: projectInstance])  

}
```